# How the Eigen value changes under extension of scalars

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, tensor-products

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension and $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $K.$ Then $V \otimes_K L $ is a $L$ vector space. If $T : V \to V$ be any $K$-linear map then $T\otimes Id : V \otimes_K L \to V \otimes_K L $ is $L$-linear map. Then I want to know if there is any connection between the eigen values of $T$ in $L$ and the eigen values of $T \otimes Id.$

Is there any reference to know about that. Thank you.

Comment: The characteristic polynomials of $T$ and $T \otimes \operatorname{Id}$ are the same (or more precisely, the characteristic polynomial of $T \otimes \operatorname{Id}$ is the image of the characteristic polynomial of $T$ under the natural inclusion $K[t] \hookrightarrow L[t]$).

Comment: Is there any reference for that ?

Comment: Probably any advanced linear algebra text should do---I don't have one on-hand. To see this, though, just recall that any basis $(e_a)$ of $V$ determines a basis $(e_a \otimes_K 1)$ of $V \otimes_K L$, and unwinding definitions shows that the matrix representation of $T$ w.r.t. $(e_a)$ is the same as the matrix representation of $T \otimes \operatorname{Id}$ w.r.t. $(e_a \otimes 1)$. (Here "the same" means that we're identifying the space of matrices $M(\dim V, K)$ with its inclusion in $M(\dim V, L)$.)